# Compute weekly returns from daily returns using Wed-to-Wed convention in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a Python/pandas newbie. I have a data set which looks like the following:

```
                PERMNO       date      gret   gvwretd
date                                             
2012-01-03   10001 2012-01-03  1.001751  1.016152
2012-01-04   10001 2012-01-04  0.989510  0.999553
2012-01-05   10001 2012-01-05  1.003525  1.002928
2012-01-06   10001 2012-01-06  0.997368  0.997093
2012-01-09   10001 2012-01-09  0.999117  1.002815
2012-01-10   10001 2012-01-10  1.003534  1.010420
2012-01-11   10002 2012-01-11  0.981074  1.000951
2012-01-12   10002 2012-01-12  0.993243  1.003046
2012-01-13   10002 2012-01-13  1.003175  0.994688
2012-01-17   10002 2012-01-17  1.013562  1.003904
2012-01-18   10002 2012-01-18  1.001784  1.012296
2012-01-19   10002 2012-01-19  0.995013  1.005580
2012-01-20   10002 2012-01-20  0.984428  1.000881
2012-01-23   10002 2012-01-23  1.017273  1.001606
2012-01-24   10002 2012-01-24  0.987489  0.999196
```

I could get all Wednesdays of a week, using df.resample('W-WED'), but I cannot merge them back correctly to the original data set so that I can compute cumulative product of returns for a week starting on Wednesday by PERMNO and DATE.

How to attack this problem?

1. Should I use the 'date' index or 'date' column to create indicators for weeks starting on Wednesday?
2. The series of dates falling on Wednesdays is shorter than the original data set. How can I merge back and fill in correctly the dates?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution after some serious effort:

```
f = lambda x: x.prod() - 1 # cumulative product of all returns ("gret": 1+ret) in each week for each firm
weekly_rets = df.groupby('PERMNO').resample('W-WED', closed='left', how=f)
```

I was wrong in the beginning thinking that I should create a new data set containing all dates that fall on Wednesday, and then merge it with the original, bigger data set, filling missing values with the appropriate Wednesday dates to create a groupby variable.

Am I missing something here?